# React-native checkbox is not working on IOs

Tags: react-native

I have checkbox in my react-native which is being displayed in android but it is not working on IOs any suggestion on how to fix it please?

```
     <CheckBox
            
              value={values.acceptTerms}
              onValueChange={value => setFieldValue('acceptTerms', value)}
            />
```

I also tried to use `react-native-community/checkbox"`  but It still did not work on IOs

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating onValueChange callback

```
<CheckBox
   onValueChange={()=>this.setState({checked:!checked})} <!-- delete -->
   value={values.acceptTerms}
   onValueChange={value => setFieldValue('acceptTerms', value)}
/>
```

Comment: Please share the complete code so can guide you accordingly

Comment: Its not rendering at all on the ios

Comment: its basically disabled

Comment: maybe it is issue with react native itself?

Comment: It's not rendering the checkbox view itself? or just not functioning only?

Comment: Its not rendering checkbox itself